# tableview data loading wrong order

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hi I've had this problem for quite a while.
When I display values on tableview, it will be correct the first time round, but when I scroll off the screen and back on, the data is then shown in the wrong row.

this is the code I use to display the info. **data** is a 2D array, **r** is the row number, and **i** is just and indication

```
textField.text = data[r][i + 1]
```

eg of problem:
Textfield in row 0 original displays 5
when it does off screen and comes back on
Textfield in row 0 is resets to 1, and Textfield in row 2 (sometimes another row) will show 5 when it is supposed to show 1.

Comment: Could you show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` snippet? I think your problem is using reuse cell, so you should reset your tableViewCell by using `prepairForSegue` method in UITableViewCell.

Comment: you need to put the code of  cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Answer (score 0):

you should use `indexPath.section` for [r] and `indexPath.row` for [i + 1] instead of your custom variable